# Вхождение точки в границы BoundedBy

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а для чего используется в ответе от сервера такая запись как boundedBy? К примеру, я хочу понять, входит ли точка со своими координатами, к примеру в Тверскую область, у которой есть координаты boundedBy. Эти границы, все-таки являются прямоугольником и точка в Москве, к примеру, тоже попадает в Тверскую область, если мы по границам тверской области построим прямоугольник.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**boundedBy** нужен, например, для того, чтобы задать границы карте, и она отображала весь объект или коллекцию объектов. Если вам нужно проверять попадание точки в некую область, следует добавлять соответствующий полигон на карту и проверять нахождение в нём точки через [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle).